# Preloading 50+ Videos on Page Load Without Affecting the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm working on a project where several videos are added to the HTML dynamically by JavaScript when they're needed to play, sort of like a remotely-controlled presentation. The order the videos will need to play is unknown at the time of page load and each video is under four seconds. However, the videos are large and naturally need to appear seamless when moving from when to the next, but since the videos are so big and, in some cases, loaded through the Internet, loading usually isn't seamless.

The way I'm adding videos right now is something like this:

```
$("body").append("<video class='onscreen' autoplay><source src='"+c.video+"'></source></video>");
```

Where `c.video` is a relative path to the video source.

Is there any way to preload videos directly from JavaScript beforehand without adding to the HTML? If not, what would be the best way to add to the HTML without having the video visibly playing and allowing for it to be dynamically added later?

I've seen several similar questions on StackOverflow (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142226/preloading-video-files-html5-playback)) but they're all concerned with adding the video and only playing it later, once loaded. I'm sure it's possible to adapt the code presented in those, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it, especially as I don't understand some of the concept (please feel free to expand on your answer a bit; I don't just want code snippets!).

If it effects things at all, this will, in the foreseeable future, only have to run on Firefox and the videos will likely all be OGV (though there may be exceptions).

Comment: Would it be reasonable for you to use the information in the question you linked to preload the first, say, two videos then begin preloading another video in the same manner after the first has finished? I can't imagine you'll be able to get 50+ videos into memory at once assuming they're more than a few seconds long.

Comment: @MikeC Unfortunately not as the order that the videos will play in is unknown at the page load. Fortunately, the majority of the videos will be under three seconds... But I am seeing the impossibility of it.

Comment: @VC.One Yup, it pauses on the last frame. The average video between half a megabyte and a megabyte with one or two videos with greater than ten megabytes. Unfortunately I'm not able to use code transitions for this project. All videos are 1080p.

Comment: @laef sorry I accidentally deleted my other comment (trying to edit but mistake happens)... The only way to have smooth transition is where all videos are already available (like game cut-scenes have all data already on disc). If in-house presentation just load from HDD, if it must be web-only then maybe just edit them into one long video then "seek" to different times of that video (ofcourse user must wait for a 50mb+ download, at this point it becomes internet speed issue not a memory issue).

Comment: @laef Thanks, I'll try to do HDD If possible (that was already my plan). Otherwise, I'll just have to cross my fingers and hope no one notices. My life in a nutshell!

Comment: Mind you why can't memory hold 50mb worth of video data?...  I mean 50 video tags in a CSS layer underneath the layer holding main background (this would now get them preloading, but not visible to user) and then just use JS to play & draw to canvas the current video (canvas is what user sees as presentation). Try it for 10 videos & see what you think then expand on that...

Comment: PS: If you load videos from HDD then the HTML itself must also run from HDD (an online html does not allow  HDD path in video tag). This is why I asked if it's gunna be a private (in-house) thing? If provate for your client only then you should use HDD option you were thinking of. Just get those _"sometimes loaded from web"_ video downloaded before you start the show...

Comment: @VC.One Which brings me back to the original question. I was worried I'd have to affect the DOM, is there any other way of preloading the files, say just in JavaScript? If so and you've hit on it, feel free to do it as an answer. If not, I guess I can just do it with HTML.